# How to create right and left buttons to move product carousel in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Investigating and, putting together my code little by little, I have achieved a carousel with the mouseup function that allows me to move the products by pressing the left button of the mouse without releasing it, so far it goes very well, well sometimes it remains as stalled, that is, without having pressed if I move the pointer moves the products.

What I want to achieve in my code is to be able to integrate two buttons, one right and one left, to also be able to move the products of the carousel in that way. How can I achieve it, can you explain to me?

```js
    var direction_slider = "up";
    var current_step = 0;
    var scroll_product = false;
    var scroll = -1;

$(function(){
    // vars for clients list carousel 
    var $product_carousel = $('.slider');
    var products = $product_carousel.children().length;
    var product_width = (products * 140); // 140px width for each client item 
    $product_carousel.css('width',product_width);

    var rotating = true;
    //var product_speed = 1800;
    //var see_products = setInterval(rotateClients, product_speed);

    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            rotating = true;
        }
    }, '#carousel');

    $product_carousel.on("mousedown", function(e) {
        scroll_product = true;
        scroll = e.pageX;
        event.preventDefault();
    }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
        scroll_product = false;
        var num = Math.floor(Math.abs(scroll - e.pageX) / 140);
        var dir = scroll - e.pageX < 0 ? "up" : "down";
        for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            var $first = $('.slider .item:first');
            var $last  = $('.slider .item:last');
            if (dir == "up") {
                $last.prependTo(".slider");
            } else {
                $first.appendTo(".slider");
            }
        }
        $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
    }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (scroll_product) {
            $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(" + ( e.pageX - scroll ) +"px, 0)")
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.carousel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 280px;
    height: 325px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
a {
    color: #8563CF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.thumbnail {
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 15%;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.p1em {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
                                        <div id="carousel">
                                            <div class="slider" style="width: 280px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
                                                    <div class="item product">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="thumbnail image">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZxrUVuOqsy0/maxresdefault.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="box p1em">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                    <h3>Prueba 1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="author">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                                <div class="price right">
                    <p>
                        <label></label>
                        <em class="item-price">$40.130,00</em>
                    </p>
                </div>
                            </div>
        </a>
    </div>  <div class="item product">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="thumbnail image">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZxrUVuOqsy0/maxresdefault.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="box p1em">
                <div class="heading ellipsis">
                    <h3>Curso de PHP 8 básico, intermedio y, avanzado. </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="author">
                    <span>Acaded</span>
                </div>
                                <div class="purchased items-center">
                    <button>Ir al curso</button>
                </div>
                            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: @Ouroborus There is also that friend function: `mouseleave: function()` or where specifically should it be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal here is to shift the order of elements to the left or right. With jQuery this is exceptionally easy.

The logic is as so:

- To shift the order to the right, select the last item, delete it, then insert before the first item
- To shift the order to the left, select the first item, delete it, then insert after the last item

To achieve this, we attach a `click` event listener to each respective button. We select all the slider items with the selector `$('.item.product')`, use [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/)  and [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the first and last items, and the [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function to delete the element. Then, to reorder, we use jQuery's [`insertBefore()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [`insertAfter()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/).

This is the result:

```js
$('#right').click(function() {
    $('.item.product').last().remove().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
})
$('#left').click(function() {
    $('.item.product').first().remove().insertAfter($('.item.product').last());
})
```

And the rest is just a matter of styling <sup>(note: uses [Material Icons](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) for the arrow icons)</sup>. Define two button elements;

```html
<button id="left" class="nav-btn"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></button>
<button id="right" class="nav-btn"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></button>
```

<sup>The "chevron_right" and "chevron_left" are icon names | [List of Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons)</sup>

Set their position to fixed so that their position isn't lost when the user scrolls. Set the `top` attribute to `calc(50vh - 50px)`, where `50vh` is half the height of the viewport and `50px` is the height of the button (to make it exactly in the "center").

A full example (best viewed in full page mode):

```js
var direction_slider = "up";
var current_step = 0;
var scroll_product = false;
var scroll = -1;

$(function() {
  $('#right').click(function() {
    $('.item.product').last().remove().insertBefore($('.item.product').first());
  })
  $('#left').click(function() {
    $('.item.product').first().remove().insertAfter($('.item.product').last());
  })
  var $product_carousel = $('.slider');
  var products = $product_carousel.children().length;
  var product_width = (products * 140);
  $product_carousel.css('width', product_width);
  var rotating = true;
  $(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      rotating = false;
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      rotating = true;
    }
  }, '#carousel');

  $product_carousel.on("mousedown", function(e) {
    scroll_product = true;
    scroll = e.pageX;
    event.preventDefault();
  }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
    scroll_product = false;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.abs(scroll - e.pageX) / 140);
    var dir = scroll - e.pageX < 0 ? "up" : "down";
    for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
      var $first = $('.slider .item:first');
      var $last = $('.slider .item:last');
      if (dir == "up") {
        $last.prependTo(".slider");
      } else {
        $first.appendTo(".slider");
      }
    }
    $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
  }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (scroll_product) {
      $(".slider").css("transform", "translate(" + (e.pageX - scroll) + "px, 0)")
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* button integration styling (start) */

#left {
  left: 10px;
}

#right {
  right: 10px;
}

.nav-btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  z-index: 100;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}


/* button integration styling (end) */

.carousel {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 280px;
  height: 325px;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

a {
  color: #8563CF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 15%;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.p1em {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <button id="left" class="nav-btn"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></button>
  <button id="right" class="nav-btn"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></button>
  <div id="carousel">
    <div class="slider" style="width: 280px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
      <div class="item product">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="thumbnail image">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZxrUVuOqsy0/maxresdefault.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="box p1em">
            <div class="heading ellipsis">
              <h3>Prueba 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="author">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="price right">
              <p>
                <label></label>
                <em class="item-price">$40.130,00</em>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item product">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="thumbnail image">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZxrUVuOqsy0/maxresdefault.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="box p1em">
            <div class="heading ellipsis">
              <h3>Curso de PHP 8 básico, intermedio y, avanzado. </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="author">
              <span>Acaded</span>
            </div>
            <div class="purchased items-center">
              <button>Ir al curso</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item product">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="thumbnail image">
            <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
          </div>
          <div class="box p1em">
            <div class="heading ellipsis">
              <h3>Spectric</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="author">
              <span>Spectric</span>
            </div>
            <div class="purchased items-center">
              <button>Check out</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```